# Macro issue, with multiple statements

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-construction, macros

```
#define RUN_SOME_STUFF(...) {                                        \
            int x = 0;                                               \
            printf("[INFO] Do some stuff here ... %d\n", ++x);       \
            {__VA_ARGS__}                                            \
            printf("[INFO] end some stuff here\n");                  \
        }
```

How I'm using it:

```
...
RUN_SOME_STUFF(
{
    // middle:
    int y;
    y = 100;
    printf("Middle\n"); 
});
...
```

Now, I know that this is considered as a (very) ugly macro, but that's the main reason i'm asking for help.

The first problem with this is, if appears any type of error, the compiler will show the last line of the macro, as the incorrect line. The printings are just examples to simplify the problem (in both code snippets), so there might be 20 line of complex, nested code, in which case that is very annoying.

The second one is that the __LINE__ is resolved the same incorrect way

& I'm sure there are many more ...

**1.** Are there any way to correct the above problems, so that the lines are correctly resolved? (some sort of compilator option maybe?, I'm using VS2008/2010)

**2.** If there's no way to make it with macro in a "cute" way, do I have any other options to do this? Simply, I just want to run some code "around"(before and after) some other code.

**Edit:** I would use this macro often, always with different "middle" content, so I can't write an inline function every time.

Comment: Is there any reason for which you want to use macro for this? If you only want to print stuff before & after another output, you should put your middle stuff in a buffer using sprintf then call a function (instead of your macro) passing the already formatted buffer that you can then output with a printf call.

Comment: As I state in my question, the printf-s are only over-simplifications, I need more complex code in place of printf-s.

Comment: you could inline a function instead.

Comment: Added an edit to my question as an answer to this comment.

Comment: Those aren't problems -- they're features.  That's the way that macro expansion is defined to work in C.  In particular, all newlines in the arguments to a macro are removed as part of the macro expansion process, so the whole thing ends up as a single line.

Comment: Well, that is kind of true, but they are problem for me.

Comment: A "quite cute" (or "quite dumb") solution is... two macros! The first one before the code and the second after: START; { my long stuff... } END;

Comment: In this case, I'm loosing the declared variables(in my example: "int x = 0").

Comment: By the way, your "int x;... ++x;" can't work. But I guess you already know it.

Comment: No,you can preserve the variables: the first macro can open a compound ("{") and the second one can close it. You can define your variables inside the first macro and use them up to the "}" inside the second macro.

Comment: Hm, okay, that's a little bit better ...

Answer (score 2):

You can split the macro in two pieces. Not pretty, but it works when the macros are paired. Below both `RUN_BEGIN;` and `RUN_END;` are written so that they need a semicolon.

```
#define RUN_BEGIN \
    do { \
        int x = 0;   \
        printf("[INFO] Do some stuff here ... %d\n", ++x);  \
        {  \
            (void)0

#define RUN_END  \
        } \
        printf("[INFO] end some stuff here: %d\n",x ); \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: Well, yeah, it's a little bit better (as it was commented before) because at least the "middle" statements's lines are resolved correctly.

Comment: Still note that the "int x = 0" here probably doesn't do what it's expected. If it's intended to keep a count of the time the code is invoked, I'd at least add a "static" before. This apply also to the previous posts.

Comment: In the real version of this macro, i use static variables (esp because it's multithreaded). But I simplified it here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would have better luck using [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html).  I haven't compiled this, but something like:

```
void runSomeStuff(void (*stuff)(void))
{
    int x = 0;                                                   
    printf("[INFO] Do some stuff here ... %d\n", ++x);       
    (*stuff)();                                           
    printf("[INFO] end some stuff here\n");    
}
```

Comment: As the later edit states, I need to do this many times, sometimes for a single statement, some times for 10 lines of code. Writing always a new function is a very messy solution.

Comment: Is it even possible that it could be messier than using a #define?

Comment: @lerosQ, most people consider too few functions to be much messier than too many.

Comment: "most people" are right, but in this case it would help much (if the solution exists ...)